# How to replace url-parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, url, string

given is an URL like `http://localhost:1973/Services.aspx?idProject=10&idService=14`.

What is the most straightforward way to replace both url-parameter values(for example 10 to 12 and 14 to 7)?

Regex, String.Replace, Substring or LinQ - i'm a little stuck.

Thank you in advance,

Tim

---

I ended with following, that's working for me because this page has only these two parameter:

```
string newUrl = url.Replace(url.Substring(url.IndexOf("Services.aspx?") + "Services.aspx?".Length), string.Format("idProject={0}&idService={1}", Services.IdProject, Services.IdService));
```

But thank you for your suggestions :)

Comment: thanks for sharing the solution. you made my day

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is my implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web; // For this you need to reference System.Web assembly from the GAC

public static class UriExtensions
{
    public static Uri SetQueryVal(this Uri uri, string name, object value)
    {
        NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
        nvc[name] = (value ?? "").ToString();
        return new UriBuilder(uri) {Query = nvc.ToString()}.Uri;
    }
}
```

and here are some examples:

```
new Uri("http://host.com/path").SetQueryVal("par", "val")
// http://host.com/path?par=val

new Uri("http://host.com/path?other=val").SetQueryVal("par", "val")
// http://host.com/path?other=val&par=val

new Uri("http://host.com/path?PAR=old").SetQueryVal("par", "new")
// http://host.com/path?PAR=new

new Uri("http://host.com/path").SetQueryVal("par", "/")
// http://host.com/path?par=%2f

new Uri("http://host.com/path")
    .SetQueryVal("p1", "v1")
    .SetQueryVal("p2", "v2")
// http://host.com/path?p1=v1&p2=v2
```

Comment: Beautiful and no side effects

Answer (score 18):

This is what I would do:

```
public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static string SetUrlParameter(this string url, string paramName, string value)
    {
        return new Uri(url).SetParameter(paramName, value).ToString();
    }

    public static Uri SetParameter(this Uri url, string paramName, string value)
    {           
        var queryParts = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query);
        queryParts[paramName] = value;
        return new Uri(url.AbsoluteUriExcludingQuery() + '?' + queryParts.ToString());
    }

    public static string AbsoluteUriExcludingQuery(this Uri url)
    {
        return url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?').FirstOrDefault() ?? String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string oldUrl = "http://localhost:1973/Services.aspx?idProject=10&idService=14";
string newUrl = oldUrl.SetUrlParameter("idProject", "12").SetUrlParameter("idService", "7");
```

Or:

```
Uri oldUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:1973/Services.aspx?idProject=10&idService=14");
Uri newUrl = oldUrl.SetParameter("idProject", "12").SetParameter("idService", "7");
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising, i'll have a closer look later.

Answer (score 8):

the C# HttpUtility.ParseQueryString utility will do the heavy lifting for you. You will want to do some more robust null checking in your final version.

```
    // Let the object fill itself 
    // with the parameters of the current page.
    var qs = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RawUrl);

    // Read a parameter from the QueryString object.
    string value1 = qs["name1"];

    // Write a value into the QueryString object.
    qs["name1"] = "This is a value";
```

Comment: Why are passing RawUrl to ParseQueryString?  There's a difference between a query string and a URL.  Shouldn't you split up the URL first in order to extract the query string?

Comment: Yeah, great answer, but if you pass the whole URL then your first argument's key is going to look like `http://localhost:50819/Request?pagenumber` instead of just `pagenumber`.

Answer (score 3):

I found this in an old code example, wouldnt take much to improve it, taking a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>>` may be better than the current delimeted string.

```
    public static string AppendQuerystring( string keyvalue)
    {
        return AppendQuerystring(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl, keyvalue);
    }
    public static string AppendQuerystring(string url, string keyvalue)
    {
        string dummyHost = "http://www.test.com:80/";
        if (!url.ToLower().StartsWith("http"))
        {
            url = String.Concat(dummyHost, url);
        }
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(url);
        string query = builder.Query;
        var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
        string[] pts = keyvalue.Split('&');
        foreach (string p in pts)
        {
            string[] pts2 = p.Split('=');
            qs.Set(pts2[0], pts2[1]);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string key in qs.Keys)
        {
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}={1}&", key, qs[key]));
        }
        builder.Query = sb.ToString().TrimEnd('&');
        string ret = builder.ToString().Replace(dummyHost,String.Empty);
        return ret;
    }
```

Usage

```
   var url = AppendQueryString("http://localhost:1973/Services.aspx?idProject=10&idService=14","idProject=12&idService=17");
```

Comment: Thank you. I used a simple replace because the page only has these both parameters but your answer is a good example for a better way ;)

Comment: You should state that the keyvalue should be correctly uri encoded for this to work. If I want to send `query=?est` with this, it will create an invalid query string

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is `String.Replace`, but you'll end up with problems if your uri looks like `http://localhost:1212/base.axd?id=12&otherId=12`

Comment: The OP's requirement cannot be met correctly with simple string replacement.

Comment: I know, hence me stating (albeit implicitly) that the most straightforward way (as asked for) isn't the correct way.

Comment: Actually i ended with using String.Replace(see my edit), it's working for my requirement.

Comment: @Tim - can I get at least an upvote if this is the answer that you liked most then?

Answer (score 2):

I have recently released [UriBuilderExtended](https://github.com/beruic/UriBuilderExtended), which is a library that makes editing of query strings on `UriBuilder` objects a breeze through extension methods.

You basically just create a `UriBuilder` object with your current URL string in the constructor, modify the query through the extension methods, and build the new URL string from the `UriBuilder` object.

Quick example:

```
string myUrl = "http://www.example.com/?idProject=10&idService=14";

UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(myUrl);

builder.SetQuery("idProject", "12");
builder.SetQuery("idService", "7");

string newUrl = builder.Url.ToString();
```

URL string  is obtained from `builder.Uri.ToString()`, not `builder.ToString()` as it sometimes renders differently to what you'd expect.

You can get the Library through [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/).

More examples [here](https://github.com/beruic/UriBuilderExtended).

Comments and wishes are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The most robust way would be to use the Uri class to parse the string, change te param values and then build the result.

There are many nuances to how URLs work and while you could try to roll your own regex to do this it could quickly get complicate handling all the cases.

All the other methods would have issues with substring matches etc and I don't even see how Linq applies here.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and i solved it with the following three lines of code that i get from the coments here (like Stephen Oberauer's solution, but less overenginieered):

```
    ' EXAMPLE: 
    '    INPUT:  /MyUrl.aspx?IdCat=5&Page=3
    '    OUTPUT: /MyUrl.aspx?IdCat=5&Page=4
    ' Get the URL and breaks each param into Key/value collection: 
    Dim Col As NameValueCollection = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RawUrl)

    ' Changes the param you want in the url, with the value you want
    Col.Item("Page") = "4"

    ' Generates the output string with the result (it also includes the name of the page, not only the params )
    Dim ChangedURL As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Col.ToString())
```

This is the solution using VB .NET but the conversion to C# is strightforward.